# "is not a function" Error from Period Updater's Stop function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$.PeriodicalUpdater.stop();
```

...gives me...

```
TypeError: Result of expression '$.PeriodicalUpdater.stop' [undefined] is not a function.
```

I've checked an double checked the [owner's manual](https://github.com/RobertFischer/JQuery-PeriodicalUpdater), I cannot figure out why this isn't working correctly.  The error is harmless for the most part, it's just the user's browser won't stop making server calls that it no longer needs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The doc says

> The function call returns a handle. You can call .stop() on this
>   handle in order to stop the updating and ignore any subsequent
>   responses. If the maximum number of calls, .stop(), or the autoStop
>   has been triggered, you can restart the updater using .restart() on
>   the handle. This handle is also passed into the callback function as
>   the fourth argument.

so it should be

```
var handle =$.PeriodicalUpdater(url, options);
handle.stop();
```

EDIT - after your comments, try

```
$.PeriodicalUpdater( url, { options, function(remoteData, success, xhr, handle){ 
  if(condition){ 
     handle.stop(); 
   } 
});
```

Comment: $.PeriodicalUpdater( url, { options, function(){ if(condition){ $.PeriodicalUpdater.stop(); } });  

That's the context in which I'm using PU.stop(), does that change anything?  It feels weird declaring a whole different PU inside the function of the PU I need to stop...  What do you think?  Thanks for your response, btw!

Comment: @user1313446 the handle is passed as the fourth argument of the function, just call stop on that. I edited my answer

Comment: Thanks, Nicola, this is a huge weight off me shoulders!

Answer (score 0):

from manual

> The function call returns a handle. You can call .stop() on this handle [...]

I think you must call stop() on handle.

ex:

```
var handle = $.PeriodicalUpdater('path',{},func);
handle.stop();
```

Comment: $.PeriodicalUpdater( url, { options, function(){ if(condition){ $.PeriodicalUpdater.stop(); } });  

That's the context in which I'm using PU.stop(), does that change anything?  It feels weird declaring a whole different PU inside the function of the PU I need to stop...  What do you think?  Thanks for your response, btw!

Comment: Sorry, I'm new.  So check mark that answer up there, right?  Thanks, you guys for the responses!